# Differential equation of circuit which contains R,L,C components

Tags: ac, differential, passive-networks

[image: circuit]

I'm having bit of a trouble finding the differential equation for this circuit.
I'm aware of how to construct the equations for simple paralel and series RLC circuits, but in this case the current valuesare different in the different components.
The real problem is even if i can find the equation for the whole circuit,my task states that i have to find the current and voltage values for each components as well.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Look up Delta-Wye transforms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve this problem you may want to use mesh or nodal analysis. Personally I would use mesh, though both will work. You will have three loops, each representing one current (*i*1, *i*2, and *i*3). You need to solve for the current in each loop for each element in terms of voltage. Remember the following identities:

Current in a capacitor:

[image]

Current in an inductor:

[image]

From these you should be able to generate your differential equations. Then you can solve the system of equations.

Answer (score 0):

Look at circuit A, it becomes like circuit B after using star to delta transformation on Z1, Z2, Z3.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpKv6g.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

And then, as you may have noticed, Z4 is in parallel with ZA, and Z5 is in parallel with ZB.

For star to delta conversion you can use the following formulas which have been taken from [this](http://circuitglobe.com/star-to-delta-and-delta-to-star-conversion.html) link.

[image]

But care that the symbols used may differ (ther are conversed). I am sure that you got the idea.

Next steps should be easy since finally you get a simple series circuit.